How to get hostname for an IP like this ? 2a03:2880:f804:19::
On my website, I a trying to verify the hostname of visitors, in order to manage bad bots, and most crawlers (e.g Google) recommends to check reverse DNS records (get hostname of visitor IP, then get ip of that hostname, they need to match).
But for some visitor ipv6 I get them formatted like this 2a03:2880:f804:19:: which seems incomplete ? I didn't work much with ipv6.
Running this command
host 2a03:2880:f804:19::

Returns "domain is non-existent"
Host 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.9.1.0.0.4.0.8.f.0.8.8.2.3.0.a.2.ip6.arpa not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Do I need to add a default record at the end of that ipv6 in order to be able to check host name ?
Because other ipv6 are longer and I can check hostname for those:
host 2a03:2880:2ff:9::face:b00c

returns
c.0.0.b.e.c.a.f.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.9.0.0.0.f.f.2.0.0.8.8.2.3.0.a.2.ip6.arpa domain name pointer fwdproxy-cco-009.fbsv.net.


:: is just a shortcut for "all zeroes between the parts before and afterwards", so it's not really that one IPv6 is longer than another (that's not possible), but that one contains more consecutive zeroes. That alone is not a reason for it to be "not real".

That is what I thought. It is "real", but what do I append in order to be able to check it ? Thanks.

I think the interpretation of your tool is correct: lots of trailing 0s. It's just that it doesn't have a RDNS entry.

With IPv6 it’s common that servers, routers and other infrastructure get reverse DNS records, but client devices don’t. What you see is not unexpected

It's not unexpected in IPv4, either. It used to be in the 1990s that many services would insist on rDNS being present, nowadays that's no longer the case (except perhaps for SMTP) – so the recommendation should be "they need to match if present". It certainly doesn't ward off bots, as bots can just as well run from a cheap VPS that comes with some generic "foo.bar.googleusercontent.com" rDNS by default.

I think rDNS does help protect against bots, *.googleusercontent.com is user content, so from google clients (not from Google itself), like .googlebot.com. I find it the most reliable way. Some crawlers like Facebook / Meta just specify classes of IPs, but it is not practical to check a bot IP against a class of millions IPs from a list, or billions of IPV6s.

@adrianTNT: It's absolutely practical and done all the time (by firewalls and routers especially). The number of IP addresses within a range is unimportant. You don't check by expanding the range and comparing against an array of million individual addresses – you check against the entire range at once by computing a netmask and doing a bitwise & AND. (In fact, the larger the range, the faster the check, though imperceptibly.) So even checking against a list of 100 IP ranges might still be faster than waiting for two DNS query responses to arrive.

@grawity_u1686 You meant for ipv6 too or just ipv4 ?

@adrianTNT: Both. The length of the address doesn't change the procedure all that much. Sure, depending on the programming language it might be very slightly easier with IPv4 addresses if you can treat it as a single uint32 (as opposed as looping over each byte/uint8), but even in the worst case with IPv6 it's only 16 AND comparisons – one for each byte – to check an address against a network prefix/netmask. (...and usually a company has far fewer IPv6 prefixes than IPv4 ones, which balances it out anyway.)

@adrianTNT: Although if you have truly a lot of prefixes to check against, you could be storing them in a 'radix tree' (or 'prefix tree' or a 'trie' or some other variation) which is designed specifically for such prefix-based lookups and a check against even a large number of prefixes can be done very fast. Similar libraries are available for various programming languages. [One of my Linux servers has a routing table of 195870 IPv6 routes – i.e. nearly 200K entries to check against – and the OS stores them in a prefix tree so that lookup is fast enough to be done for every single packet.]

@adrianTNT: But in the simple case of "I've got ~200 network prefixes in a PHP array and I want to check each one in turn", all you need is a "CIDR match" function/library/module (I've written one in some 20 lines of PHP, written one in Bash, other people have written like 50 variations of the same thing too) and even that can be fast enough to be done in each HTTP request. Even for IPv6.
